# Check mouse event and keyboard event all tabs in a browser using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to check the mouse event or keyboard event in all tabs for a URL which is open in more then 1 tabs in a browser. means i have Login in a site  and open a other tabs but in other tabs i want to check mouse event fire or not.

Comment: The pages opened in other tabs in the browser are also the same page right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 onkeypress
```

this can be used to capture keypress

```
    onclick     
    onmouseup.
    onmousedown     
    ondblclick
```

These canb be used to capture mose events

Comment: yes , i know that but if i open page multiple tabs  in browser , it does not check events in all tabs. please advice,

Comment: than try to implement it dynamically `$('.yourtabs').each(function() { $(this).click(function(){ $('.yourinputs').onclick( /* your logic here */ ); }); });`